# imutils doesn't read all paths opencv

Tags: python

say I have a folder that contains 10000 images whenever I want to read the path of the images folder I use imutils here:

```
import imutils as paths
path=list(paths.list_images(folderpath))
```

now assume that my folder contains 10000 images with names ("1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg",etc.)
now what i want is that path list contain the path of each image but when i display it gives me this
`["path\1.jpg","path\10.jpg","path\100.jpg","path\1000.jpg","path\10000.jpg"]`
so how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried os.walk?

```
import os 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if ".jpg" in name:
            path_name = os.path.join(root, name)
```

Comment: I did try it but it gives me the same result

Comment: Could you post a example of how you want your result?